# Apache camel: Stop exchange from proceeding to delete=true

Tags: java, apache-camel, esb, dsl

I want to only allow non-duplicate files to be deleted from the source directory. I have a route with idempotent consumer like this:

```
File repo = new File("repo.txt");
IdempotentRepository fr = FileIdempotentRepository.fileIdempotentRepository(repo);

from("sftp:someServer:somePort/someDir?delete=true")
    .idempotentConsumer(header("CamelFileName"),fr)
    .to("file:output");
```

In this case, delete=true will cause a route to delete duplicate messages as well from the source directory.To prevent this, I've tried the following code:

```
File repo = new File("repo.txt");
IdempotentRepository fr = FileIdempotentRepository.fileIdempotentRepository(repo);

from("sftp:someServer:somePort/someDir?delete=true")
    .idempotentConsumer(header("CamelFileName"),fr)
    .skipDuplicate(false)
    .filter(exchangeProperty(Exchange.DUPLICATE_MESSAGE).isEqualTo(true))
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                exchange.setException(new InterruptedException("Cancel Exchange"));
                exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE);
            }
         })
    .end()
.to("file:output");
```

Since deleting from sftp inside the route will require another jsch instance, I'd prefer to be able to use the sftp consumer's delete property

Comment: You might want a custom idempotent repository implementation that reverses the logic for `boolean add(E key)` and `boolean contains(E key)`. By default `add` will return true if the repository did not yet contain an entry and therefore could be added to the backing store, while `contains` has just the opposite logic. You basically want to return true if already an entry exist while attempting to add the key to the backing store via `add(...)` and returning false when checking if the repository contains the entry. Haven't tried something like that yet though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can be wrong but delete=true causing deleting processed messages, not duplicated.You configure idempotent repo inside route, but need to configure sftp consumer with idempotent repo. After that consumer will stops consuming and deleting already processed files if they will appears in folder again. Like this:

```
from("sftp:someServer:somePort/someDir?delete=true&idempotent=true&idempotentRepository=#yourRepo")
```

Comment: The issue is both processed and duplicate messages are deleted with idempotent EIP. I'll try using the endpoint with idempotent

Comment: As i said that's cause you consuming both files (original and duplicated). Consumer will delete any file that processed without exception. That's how delete=true works. You can throw exception when your in-route idempotent repo find duplicate and consumer will not delete it, but it isn't good approach.

Comment: Idempotent readlock is not available for ftp endpoints and I was probably confused with that and just idempotent consumer. This is the correct answer. Also, add idempotent=true to the endpoint options in the code snippet :)

Comment: Mark answer as correct, someone should read comments for finding out that it helps you.